# Why is the bond angle of AB3E1 approximately 109.5?

Tags: vsepr-theory

[image]

Since there are 3 B atoms and the angle between each atom is equal, shouldn't the bond angle be equal to 120?

Comment: Your drawing shows you why.

Comment: How does your second statement follow from the first. You seem to be ignoring something else around the central atom.

Comment: Aren't all 3 B atoms on the same plane?  And if so, doesn't that mean, to maximize distance from each other, that they will occupy as much of 360 degrees as possible?  To occupy the maximum amount of space, they have to be at 120 degrees.

Comment: How is it possible that you put picture with **huge** lone pair, while being ignorant about her influence?

Comment: I understand that a lone pair will cause greater electron repulsion and subsequently make the angles smaller.  However, would the angle between the B with straight line and the B with the dashed line also be 109.5?

Comment: Yes all three B-A-B angles are equal to 109.5

Comment: But if all three B-A-B angles = 109.5 and all three B-A-B angles are on a plane, then their total sum has to equal 360 degrees.  109.5 degrees would not make this add up.  And if the lone pair squished the three angles together, then angle B (with the solid straight line) - A - B (dashed line) should be greater than 109.5.  But since all the angles are 109.5, this cannot be the case.  Clearly I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: True. Then consider an idea that all three B-A-B angles are **not** on a plane.